# Latex not displaying?

Tags: support, status-completed, mathjax

When I visit sites like physics.stackexchange and math.stackexchange, instead of seeing the latex that I am used to, I see the dollar signs as though it hasn't compiled. This has just started recently and I am not sure why. Has this happened to anyone else? How can I fix this?

Comment: have you installed a new userscript or extension recently? It happens to me as well, but only on [math.se] and not in the private mode.

Comment: No I don't believe so

Comment: Check your Javascript  console

Comment: I think you are correct, I have https everywhere on google chrome. I opened up firefox and it worked perfectly. That might be the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in the comments, the issue was caused by HTTPS Everywhere. SE sites are now accessible via HTTPS, but MathJax -- the script that renders LaTeX -- is still served via HTTP only. Since browsers typically disallow such a mix of secure-unsecure content, LaTeX is not rendered when using HTTPS (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/).

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220072/251274 ([status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)).